# dpkg install fails due to conflicts from another package

Tags: uninstallation, dpkg, debian-packaging

I have built 2 debian packages (abc.deb and xyz.deb) using dpkg-deb tool.
The directory structure for them are:
pkg1:
/opt/pqr/xyz
pkg2:
/opt/pqr/abc

Both share a dependancy pkg (oss.deb) which is also installed under /opt/pqr as:
/opt/pqr/oss

The intent is to have all my packages under /opt/pqr

The issue I am facing is:
Step1: install oss.deb
this results in:
/opt/pqr/oss

Step2: install abc.deb using dpkg -i abc.deb
This results in:

```
/opt/pqr/abc/
/opt/pqr/oss/
```

Step3: install xyz.deb
This step is replacing / deleting abc.deb and installing xyz resulting in:

```
/opt/pqr/xyz
/opt/pqr/oss
```

My expectation at the end of step3:

```
/opt/pqr/abc
/opt/pqr/oss
/opt/pqr/xyz
```

I think since the path /opt/pqr is created with both packages during installation, dpkg is trying to remove them too. Is there a way to workaround this issue where I could only delete /opt/pqr/abc during dpkg -r abc.deb and similarly delete only /opt/pqr/xyz during dpkg -r xyz.deb ?

Answer (score 1):

i got the issue. I had the package name same in both abc.deb and xyz.deb DEBIAN/control file which created the issue. Fixing the package name fixed the issue.